# Differentiate if Change Event is called from filter or success function (Ajax Datatable Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using jQuery's AJAX Datatable plugin where I am firing a `draw.dt` event every time the Datatable is redrawn to find the change on the Datatable. I need to differentiate between if the event (Datatable redrawn) is fired on the success function or from a filter. How can I do that?

```
$('.dataTable', "#formElement").on('draw.dt', function () {
  // Custome Logic
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "success function" ...?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? most of the times you can handle different events or take a different approach instead of handling the draw event, which can be slow.

Comment: @davidkonrad    
 Success function is basically, I add/remove rows after performing CURD operation. On its success, Datatable is redrawn(Data added or deleted respectively).

I want to Detect the change in Datatable when the row is added, deleted or updated dynamically.

Right now I am using 'draw.dt' event which works fine but it also gets fired on Filters(Search) of Datatable.

I want to Perform some logic only when I have performed CURD operation not when I filtered(searched) datatable

Comment: @Sebastianb
 I want to Detect the change in Datatable when the row is added, deleted or updated dynamically. Right now I am using 'draw.dt' event which works fine but it also gets fired on Filters(Search) of Datatable. I want to Perform some logic only when I have performed CURD operation not when I filtered(searched) datatable

Comment: @SwapnilBapat, since you are in full control over the CRUD executing, why not fire your own event instead of trying to accomplish something impossible with the built-in event..? There is no way to distinguish why the `draw.dt` event is fired on a custom level like this. It is just fired because the table is being redrawn.

Comment: @davidkonrad

Yes, I can do that, But I have to use same functionality multiple times. I am trying to centralise it and avoid code redundancy.